# Guake Doesn't Start When Session Starts

Tags: guake

I've Ubuntu 12.04 installed.

I've added guake to startup applications but it doesn't work. All programs listed in startup application are working except guake. What should I do?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally solved.

From Guake Preferences, uncheck "enable popup notifications on startup".

Then add guake to Startup Applications and that's all.

Startup Applications can be found via the dash, this image shows an example of editing a startup but adding would be exactly the same.

If you want to easily find the path to an application you can issue the which command

```
$ which guake
```

Which would return

```
/usr/bin/guake
```

[image: Dialog showing example of adding an entry to startup applications]

Answer (score 0):

In Guake general options check "launch guake at login" et voilà !

(Compatible with all other check box)

Answer (score -1):

Should not happen again with the [latest Guake version](https://github.com/guake/guake).