# Guake does not start automatically

Tags: autostart, startup-applications, guake

How can I make Guake start on boot?

Guake is installed and works fine via manual startup (typing `guake` in a terminal works e.g).

When I press `Super` and type "Startup Applications" Guake is there, using the command "guake" (simple one should think. But no). It doesn't work. I can not open Guake via the keyboard shortcut and top in terminal does not show anything that says "guake", that is until I open it manually.

I have also tried `sudo cp /usr/share/applications/guake.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/` but with no result.

Any ideas?

I am using [Gnome Ubuntu 13.04](http://ubuntugnome.org/faq/), but don't think it is related to my specific system since I have encountered the problem on my previous systems (also Ubuntu based however), but haven't bothered researching it till now.

Comment: Try to edit the startup application command from `guake` to `/usr/bin/guake` or `/bin/guake` . Search and find where guake is lying. If not works, then check the `.xsession-errors` file for any useful error messages.

Comment: Does the keyboard shortcut work after you start it manually? Also have you added any other programs to Startup Applications?

Comment: NikTh: guake is located in `/usr/bin/` (nothing guakey in `/bin/` what so ever) but changing the startup command to `/usr/bin/guake` did not make any difference. I can not find the `.xsession-errors` file in my home directory. Shouldn't it be there?

Steelsouls: Yes it does and yes I have (and other programs work well).

Comment: I found [this other question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/136559/guake-doesnt-start-when-session-starts?rq=1) that might solve your problem. If so, I'll mark this as a duplicate. If not, I have another idea for you that I'll type up as an answer when I get home.

Comment: Oh yes - that did the trick! Thank you very much! This should be marked as a duplicate (I find the other title a bit unclear (a session could mean many things. But I guess "start automatically" could do as well), so therefore I did not look into it before).