# How to make Guake start at login?

Tags: startup, guake

I had to reinstall Ubuntu and always used Guake Terminal and it was always starting when the desktop appeared and I only pressed <kbd>F12</kbd> and it did everything I had to.

But now it doesn't start automatically. I was looking for an answer but nothing worked. Has anybody ideas how to solve it ? It would be really nice to use it as earlier ;)

Comment: This worked for me
http://askubuntu.com/questions/136559/guake-doesnt-start-when-session-starts

Answer (score 80):

Goto *Activities* or to Show Applications menu and type *Startup Applications*.

[image: screenshot]

The *Startup Application Preferences* window opens. Then, click in *Add*, give a name for the application in the *Name* field ("Guake" it's enough), and then type “guake” without quotes in the *Command* field and click *Add*. Then close the *Startup Application Preferences* window and restart the machine, now Guake should start automatically on login.

[Source](http://nasarabna.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/autostart-guake-during-system-startup/)

Comment: Guake can be found here: /usr/bin/guake (if needed), else just type it like Chechus said ;-)

Comment: This worked nicely for me on 16.04.

Answer (score 26):

Have you tried adding it to the startup applications (search "startup applications")

If you have, try adding a .desktop file to  `/etc/xdg/autostart/`

You can do this with the following command

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/applications/guake.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/
```

This is just an example, I don't know what the guake .desktop file is named but you can easily find out by having a look in the map: /usr/share/applications/

If by chance that doesn't work as well then there is one other solution you could try adding the following command to the startup applications

```
bash -c "sleep 10 && guake"
```

If it doesn't work try varying the sleep time because it depends on your system's speed but usually 10 seconds will work just fine.

Comment: I tried it with the Startup Applications and it didn't work earlier, the same now. But adding the desktop file solved the problem ! ;) Thanks very much !

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/guake.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/
```

Comment: You posted this six months after @akisame posted a better answer. Use a symbolic link, don't make another copy.

Answer (score 3):

This helps for me:

[Guake Doesn't Start When Session Starts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136559/guake-doesnt-start-when-session-starts)

In Guake's preferences just uncheck Enable notifications on startup, and add the full path (e.g. `/usr/bin/guake) to startup applications.

Answer (score 0):

`locate guake.desktop` then do,

```
$ cp /usr/share/applications/guake.desktop ~/.config/autostart/
$ echo "X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true" >> guake.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

You may rather use `guake --hide` at startup for just opening the prgrm in background and not the terminal window until `F12` is pressed.