# Used crontab -e, but script doesn't run

Tags: cron, startup

I used `crontab -e`, getting the below, which I then edited (adding the final line):

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command

@reboot guake
```

But guake still doesn't run on startup. Why?
I also tried `@reboot ./script`, and the script won't run. Both work in the terminal usually.

Comment: Where is the `guake` binary? cron jobs run with a minimal `PATH`, so binaries anywhere except /bin or /usr/bin will not be found. Can `guake` run before you've logged in? Does it have any other environment dependencies (cron jobs run with a very minimal environment)? Have you tried capturing its output (and errors) by adding something like `>/tmp/guake.log 2>&1` to the command? Check the [canonical question over on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it) for more ideas.

Comment: I just want to run guake on startup. This is what the guide said to do.

Comment: Which guide? I tried googling, but didn't see anything relevant.

Comment: Second answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

Comment: That's talking about shell scripts, not interactive GUI programs. (And it's common for shell scripts to fail due to cron's minimal environment.) Try the answers to: [How to make Guake start at login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368705/how-to-make-guake-start-at-login)

Comment: I also tried a shell script called "view" using the line ./view. How do I just run a command at start up, without first opening a terminal and running it? For example, I have a script "view" which alters my monitor resolution. It is in my home folder. I just run ./view. But I need it to run automatically.

Comment: It really depends on what the script/program does, what its dependencies are, etc. The options in that other question are much more likely to work, but there's no single always-works answer.